# Zapier & BambooHR Zap

Tags: json, zapier

I'm new to this, and trying to reach myself some of the basics. I'm trying to setup a zap to allow a user email attachment to be posted to an employees file in BambooHR using a zap. So, trigger email received from user and action, code - to upload the email attachment into BambooHR into a particular employees folder. So, I would need to include the employees number in the first part of the zap.

Below is bamboo documentation for the code (basically, to upload an employee file) https://www.bamboohr.com/api/documentation/employees.php

Can anyone provide any steps for me to follow. I'm new at this, but learning quickly. I've included a [screenshot](http://post/api/gateway.php/%7Bjerseyinitiatives%7D/v1/employees/%7B23232222%7D/misc/) and where I got to so far in setting up the zap.

Here is the code that I think I figured out after reading Bamboo's API Doc.

post/api/gateway.php/{jerseyinitiatives}/v1/employees/{23232222}/misc/

Thanks,

Comment: Hey there! I believe the linked screenshot isn't a screenshot at all. Do you mind updating it?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.bitium.com/zapier-bamboo-hr-integration ?